# Can I disable my local font in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, font-face, typeface

I work on a system who always bug with the google font load, but i can't see when the font is not loaded because I have all these font in local (for Photoshop) so the font look like good on my computer.

So, I would like to disable all these font in chrome so I can see quickly if the google font is correctly load or not.

**Do you think it's possible ??**

Thank you

PS: Excuse my english, i'm French.

Comment: Temporarily remove them? E.g. move them out of \fonts on Windows

Comment: yes but i'm more searching a general that i can integrate to my workflow

Comment: you can change font name in your css. you can set name of your font in font-face syntax, like below :

@font-face{ font-family: **myCustomFontName**; src: url(FontName.ttf);}

Just change myCustomFontName to something unlike font name in local system.

Comment: @youngshot did you ever find a way, or did you rename?

Comment: Not in Chrome, but in Firefox: see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76903494/1334619) to the question "Disable installed fonts from system in browser".

Answer (score 5):

Rather than disabling the fonts on your side of things, why not use the [font API](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-font-loading/#fontfaceset) in Chrome or Opera and have run through all the fonts that have been specified as follows?

```
document.fonts.ready.then(function(set) {
  // Log that the fonts are loaded
  console.log(set);
  var t;
  for(var t of set.entries()) {
    console.log(t); 
  }
});
```

The `FontFaceSet` will tell you if the font has been loaded or not.

Answer (score 4):

On Chrome/Brave you can now see where the font was loaded from. Go to `view` —> `developer` –> `inspect elements` –> make sure the `elements` tab is selected –> select the `computed` sub-tab –> scroll to the bottom and look for `rendered fonts`. If it's a local file it'll say `YOUR_FONT – local file`.

[image]

---

### Bonus:

If using a Mac, then you can disable the local font in the Font Book application. Just open that app, then find the font you want to disable, right click, and select `Disable "YOUR_FONT" Family`. Then refresh the page and you should see what the user without that font will see.

[image]

Comment: You did not explain what to do with it.  There are no buttons there.  (I'm not using a Mac)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying here @YanKingYin, there are no buttons where? Specifically where are you getting stuck?