# How to force Chrome to ignore locally installed Google fonts?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In development, I want to test whether a Google font is loading correctly on a page. However, the Google font always loads for me because I have it installed locally on my development machine.

Is there a way to tell the browser to ignore a locally installed font, specifically, within Google Chrome?

Comment: Not in Chrome, but in Firefox: see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76903494/1334619) to the question "Disable installed fonts from system in browser".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered that on a Mac (OS X), I can disable any font in the "Font Book" app that comes standard on the Mac.
[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVJkR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Either delete local fonts either rename them to something different.

I think there is no other solution because Google adds `local('font name')` to `src` in `@font-ace`:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Open Sans Light'), local('OpenSans-Light'), url(...) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F;
}
```