# How to turn off local fonts to test google fonts?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, fonts, google-font-api

Prior art:

- [Can I disable my local font in chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21312638/can-i-disable-my-local-font-in-chrome)
- https://superuser.com/questions/292666/how-to-disable-permission-to-read-system-fonts-and-browser-plugin-details-in

Is there a way to disable system fonts temporarily in any browser?

The only solution I can find is to name the font something that doesn't collide with local fonts. I don't like that solution cause:

1. I'd rather refer to fonts by correct name.
2. It doesn't work with inline fonts via stylesheet like how Google serves fonts.

So, anyone know how?

Comment: 1) why? `@font-face { font-family: main; src: local(...); }` is perfectly fine, and means you don't have to change a million `font-family` instances just because because you decide to switch font. It is, in fact, good practice. 2) google serves fonts in several ways, including as normal CSS `<link rel="stylesheet">`, which is by far the easiest to work with.

Comment: 1) To test performance, for example.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you are on a Mac just open up the 'Font Book' app and disable the font.

Comment: And if you're on Windows?

Comment: This doesn't work with Apple-installed fonts so isn't a good solution for some fonts that may not be installed on non-Apple systems.

Answer (score 11):

From Chrome 86, you can now disable local fonts in DevTools.

1. Open DevTools
2. Click the three dots in the top right
3. Select **More tools** > **Rendering**
4. Check **Disable local fonts**
5. Refresh the page

This will ignore all `local(...)` sources in CSS `@font-face` rules.

Comment: Unfortunately, this **Disable local fonts** option does not do what I expected it to do at first, before I read the detail. For my [use case](https://community.coreldraw.com/talk/coreldraw-graphics-suite-2019/f/coreldraw-graphics-suite-2019-for-windows/63222/export-to-svg-embeds-fonts-in-deprecated-svg-font-format-no-longer-supported-by-most-browsers), I want to stop Chrome (or any modern browser, for that matter) using fonts that are installed on the local computer: **Ignore installed fonts**. This isn't it.

Comment: I tried this but didn't work, I had to disable the font from the system

Answer (score 1):

Rather than renaming the `font-family`, I would just omit or comment out the `local()` function call in your `src` descriptor. Without it, the browser will always load the font file(s) specified in your `url()` function(s).

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "My Font";
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    src:
        /* --> local("My Font") <-- */
        url("/my-font.woff2") format("woff2"),
        url("/my-font.woff") format("woff")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to disable system fonts temporarily in any browser?

Yes.

In Firefox, use one of the following preferences:

- `layout.css.font-visibility.standard`
- `font.system.whitelist`

For details, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76903494/1334619) to the question "Disable installed fonts from system in browser".